# Problem Using Active Reports in Angular 8

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

i tried to use Active Reports in Angular 8 and i did all the steps needed from this website,https://www.grapecity.com/activereportsjs/docs/GettingStarted/QuickStart/QuickStart-Angular
Still i get this error when i try to compile my app :

```
ERROR in The target entry-point "@grapecity/activereports-angular" has missing dependencies:
 - rdlx-model
 - @grapecity/ar-js-viewer/ExportPanel
 - @grapecity/viewer-core
 - @grapecity/ar-js-viewer
 - @grapecity/viewer-core/features/search
```

and this is **my code :**

**In App.Component.Html**

```
gc-activereports-viewer [height]="height" [availableExports]="availableExports" (documentLoaded)="onDocumentLoaded($event)" #reportviewer></gc-activereports-viewer
```

**In App.Module.Ts**

```
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';<br />
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';<br />
   import { ActiveReportsModule } from '@grapecity/activereports-angular';
   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

   @NgModule({<br />
     declarations: [<br />
       AppComponent<br />
     ],<br />
     imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       ActiveReportsModule
     ],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })<br />
   export class AppModule { }
```

**In App.Component.Ts**
 i used the exact same Code from the website.(Grapecity.com)
and the rest of the steps;
i used to run this Command as adminstrator `**npm install @grapecity/activereports-angular**` and it didn't work either 
**CMD page shows me this message :

```
**<br /> D:\Angular Projects\Reporter-so>  npm install @grapecity/activereports-angular<br />
npm WARN @grapecity/activereports-angular@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.<br />
npm WARN @grapecity/activereports-angular@1.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.<br />
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents):<br />
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this code in tsconfig.app.json

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```